# Child of constraint two hands problem

Tags: armature, constraints, vertex-groups

Working on this fps animation and im trying to get the left hand to hold and move along with the gun like the right hand, but the gun bone has already been set a constraint for the right hand. The gun bone is also connected to the vertex of the gun mesh, so making another bone wouldn't work. Best way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Did you repost this?

Comment: No, i just logged in and couldnt comment on the answer on the last question to ask, i tried the solution and all i need now is the left hand, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Why not use another Child Of constraint for the left hand? Make the right hand the target?

Comment: Didn't work, the left hand would just rotate unaccurately, even if i set it for the sleeve

Comment: Why not share your file? https://blend-exchange.com